# Помогите решить две задачи на JS

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь решить уже часа два, помогите:
1. Найти натуральное число из интервала от а до b, у которого количество делителей максимальна. Если таких чисел несколько, то должно быть найдено максимальное из них. 
2. Дано натуральное число. Найти числа, образованные из исходного приписыванием к нему такого же числа.
 Буду благодарен за решение на js.

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/ — особое внимание на функции, циклы, операторы и условные операторы. Вернитесь через пару дней, с попытками решения))

Comment: у меня нету времени на пару дней)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME скажите я могу скинуть в ответ свое решение неполное не знаю как сделать макс колво делителей ?

Comment: Да, можешь кинуть мне.

Comment: Арчи 2 зачада приписываемое это знак сложения ?

Comment: Вторую задачу я решил уже, мне бы первую.

Comment: Арчи мне бы тоже первую :)

Comment: Лекс, ты вторую решил как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аффтару: Ответ написан из-за интереса в комментариях. Обычно не принято отвечать на вопросы "сделайте за меня" )

Решение первой задачи: Из интервала, нахождение числа с максимальным количеством делителей.

```js
console.log( maxDividersFromRange(1, 100) );

function maxDividersFromRange(a, b){
  let max = findDividers(a).length; // Сразу находим кол-во делителей первого числа
  // Изначально считаем его самым большим.
  let info = {
    [max]: [a]
  }; // Каждое найденное КОЛИЧЕСТВО делителей будет являться ключем в объекте info
  // И будет хранить в себе массив чисел (пока что там 1 элеент, число [a])
  
  for( let i = a + 1; i <= b; i++ ){
    let divs = findDividers(i).length;
    if( info[divs] ){ // Если в объекте уже есть это количество делителей как ключ
      info[divs].push( i ); // Добавить в его массив текущее число
    } else { // Иначе - создать новый ключ и массив с [текущим числом]
      info[divs] = [i];
    }
    if( divs > max ){
      max = divs; // Обновляем максимальное количество делителей, если новое оказалось больше него.
    }
  }

  let foundNums = info[max]; // Массив чисел с макс. количеством делителей.
  // Можно было циклом пройтись по нему и искать самое большое число.
  // Но из предыдущих шагов понятно, что самым большим окажется последний элемент
  maxOfThem = foundNums[foundNums.length - 1]; // Сразу берем его.
  
  setTimeout( () => console.log( JSON.stringify(info) ) ); // Чтобы было видно что происходит
  
  return maxOfThem + ', Делители: ' + findDividers(maxOfThem).join(", ");
}

function findDividers(num){
  let dividers = [];
  let temp = num;
  
  while( temp >= 2 ){
    for( let i = 2; i <= temp; i++ ){
      if( temp % i == 0 ){
        temp = temp / i;
        dividers.push(i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return dividers;
}
```

Массив чисел "с одним делителем" — По совместительству простые числа))

Answer (score 0):

1. Первая задача так ?

```js
function sum(a, b, c){

  for( let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
    if( arguments[i] > a && arguments[i] < c ){
      console.log( arguments[i] )
    }
  }

}
sum(2, 3, 4)
```

2. Вторая задача так ?

   ```js
   function number(a){
     return a += a;
     // return a *= a;
   }
   console.log( number(2) );
   ```

Comment: @Арчи так примерно

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME посмотрите пожалуйста и скажите у меня правильно сделано ?

Comment: Вторая... получая 2, должна возвращать 22. Поэтому `return "" + a + a;` или `return Number("" + a + a);` )

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME тогда вот так return `${a}` + a :))  получается я не до конца второй вопрос понял ...

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME спасибо что потратили свое личное время

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Спасибо!

Comment: @Арчи мог ли бы и галочку поставить OPTIMUS PRIME